# Basic Wiring Help

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, 12v, isolation, module

I’m an individual that likes to tinker around with things and I’m asking for help.

I’m in the middle of a car audio system update.  I currently use a basic relay as a “turn-on” switch for my amplifiers and 2 small computer cooling fans.

The relay is the venerable Tyco/Bosch 30 Amp unit with a diode across pins 86 and 85.  The relay is connected as follows:

[image]

I’m upgrading to higher end car amplifiers and in one of the forums that I’ve been a member from Germany said to me: “use a electronic Relais with optocoupler”

So I looked on Amazon and found this little guy:
HiLetgo 12V 1 Channel Relay Module With Optocoupler Isolation Support High or Low Level Trigger https://a.co/d/cKaYPZd

I’m pretty confused with the input side and the output side.  I’m that guy that knows just enough to constantly get in trouble.  This is what I came up with:

[image]

Is this remotely correct??

Basically, I’m trying to relocate the wiring from the regular ole relay to this fancier one with the octocoupler.

One more thing, the jumper, should I have it on High or Low?

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.  Apparently European hi-end car audio enthusiasts are more likely to use this relay than here in the US.  Basically what I gather is the relay with the octocoupler should give me an extra layer of protection to prevent any possible feedback that could damage my amplifiers.

Rick

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING.

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand.  Was I shouting?

Comment: Typing in all capitals is seen as rude, in a similar way to if you were shouting your question.

Comment: It was just the title.  Fixed it.

Comment: The title is the first thing we see remember...